# Youtube shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to make this shortcode work but without any success. All attempts gives me a white square.

```
  function youtube($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "value" => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhWopzlRwZ8',
    "width" => '475',
    "height" => '350',
    "name"=> 'movie',
    "allowFullScreen" => 'true',
    "allowScriptAccess"=>'always',
    ), $atts));
    return '<object style="height: '.$height.'px; width: '.$width.'px"><param name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="'.$allowFullScreen.'"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="'.$allowScriptAccess.'"></param><embed src="'.$value.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="'.$allowFullScreen.'" allowScriptAccess="'.$allowScriptAccess.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></embed></object>';
    }
    add_shortcode("youtube", "youtube");
```

Comment: And what is the problem with it? What do you mean by "white square"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few remarks about your code:

**1)** First you should use something like:

https://www.youtube.com/v/EhWopzlRwZ8

instead of the YouTube page:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhWopzlRwZ8

in your embed code.

**2)** You can always use the `[embed]` shortcode if you need to embed YouTube videos:

```
[embed width="600" height="400"]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhWopzlRwZ8[/embed]
```

**3)** You should consider adding a *prefix* to your shortcode callback, for example `macko_tarana_` to avoid function name collision with other plugins.

**4)** Try to avoid `extract(...`, use `$atts = shortcode_atts(...`  instead.

**5)** Consider atting the third parameter to `shortcode_atts`, i.e. the shortcode name so you can use the `shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filter. More about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) in the Codex.

**6)** Always **escape** the input attributes, for example with `esc_attr()` or `esc_url()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for point #5. I so get fed up by this that I edited Codex and left a note about it.

Comment: thanks @kaiser. I agree and usually the third attribute is  missing when you really need it ;-)